# Tracert dns behaviour explanation

Tags: dns, wireshark, traceroute

I'm trying to understand how tracert works. While sniffing packets with Wireshark I noticed that sometimes tracert decides to not resolve the host name.
Here are some examples:
tracert http://www.google.com ----> 0 packets
tracert guuugle                    -----------------------> 0 packets
tracert w.guugle              ----------------------> DNS query

I mean why in the first two examples I don't see any packets? How can it know that those hosts don't exist?
(DNS are flushed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system will not resolve `http://www.google.com` because it knows that's not a *valid* hostname. It's an URL, and it has a hostname *in* it, but it's not a hostname itself. The OS knows this because neither the `:` nor `/` are allowed in hostnames (that's why URLs use them as separators!).

In your second example, the name doesn't have any dots in it, so many systems consider it a local name and try other (non-DNS) methods of resolving it first. Although that's not a strict rule – some other systems *do* attempt to resolve single-component names via DNS as well (although often they append the "local domain" at the end).